# Enterprise Development Profile VS Enterprise Distribution Profile

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mdm

We are using MDM solution to distribute the apps because it is secure and requires no user interaction.

Now we have been deploying App via MDM using `Enterprise Development Profile` instead of `Enterprise Distribution Profile` as we are in development. Everything is working fine. My question is: what difference will it make in both the cases if in one case, I use Enterprise Development Profile and in other case, I use Enterprise Distribution Profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build an app with a **development provisioning profile**, you can debug it on the device. The **development provisioning profile** is the only provisioning profile that enables debugging on the device. With this type of provisioning profile, you can run your apps only on the ***devices*** included in the provisioning profile and you cannot publish apps in the App Store/MDM Store.

If you want to develop and distribute apps privately within your company or to a selected number of end users, you can use a **provisioning profile for in-house distribution**.

When you build and code sign an app with a pair of matching cryptographic identity and provisioning profile for in-house distribution, you can distribute the app outside of the App Store to the devices registered in your iOS Developer Enterprise Program. You can use an in-house cryptographic identity and provisioning profile to build and code sign private company apps.

Comment: With using Enterprise Development Profile..I have been able to deploy my App to MDM successfully. I don't know how it has been working.